# ESLint terminated with error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, eslint

I'm running the following code through ESLint:

```
/*global $, jQuery,alert*/
//jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    jQuery('.toggle-nav').click(function (e) {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I'm getting "ESLint terminated with error: timeout". Can anyone help me in understanding and eliminating this error?

Comment: I removed "enter code here" from your code block, since it appears to be an artifact of the site's text editor, not part of your actual code.

Comment: Can you show how you are invoking ESLint? Is this from the command line?